# Output from Ajax $.post() function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){           

    $('#lform').submit(function(){
        $.post(
        'processor.php',
        $(this).serialize(),
        //here, where we're going to manage the output data from the login.php
        function(output){
            var ss = output;
            if (ss === "correct"){
                alert (ss);
            }else{
                $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 20}, 800);
                $('#error').html(output);
                });
            }       
                return false;       
    });         

});
```

As you can see from the above codes, it simply posts the form data to `processor.php` and then handles the response from it. It stores the output first into a `var ss` and then checks to see is the output is equal to "correct". If it is, then it alerts "correct", otherwise it outputs the response to `#error`.

The codes above is working but there is something wrong on it whenever the respond is equal to correct,  an alert box saying correct is not showing up instead the respond was put in the #error element

Comment: Can you tell us what you get when you console.log your output variable?

Comment: I agree with @RobertKotcher, console output would be appreciated. That's the easiest way to tell what's going wrong. If you're using firefox (and firebug) or Chrome, it's easy to see the POST and the response from the console, and you can go from there.

Comment: The codes above is working but there is something wrong on it whenever the respond is equal to correct,  an alert box saying correct is not showing up instead the respond was put in the #error element

Comment: You cannot `return false` to the `submit` event handler from an *asynchronous* request handler. You will need to `preventDefault()` in every case, and once the ajax request suggests validity you have to manually submit it again.

Comment: Could the response include white-space? Maybe try ss.trim() == "correct"

Comment: yay its working, thanks @Joel! this ss.trim() == "correct" really moved the headache out of my head!

Comment: thanks @Bergi, for your suggestions/recommendations about preventDefault() it really helps alot!

Answer (score 1):

Your scope braces are in the wrong order and will break your function from even running:

```
        }else{
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 20}, 800);
            $('#error').html(output);
            });
        }

            return false;
```

should be:

```
        }else{
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 20}, 800);
            $('#error').html(output);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The codes above is working but there is something wrong on it whenever the respond is equal to correct,  an alert box saying correct is not showing up instead the respond was put in the #error element

Answer (score 0):

```
   }else{
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 20}, 800);
            $('#error').html(output);
            });
        }
```

should be:

```
  }else{
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 20}, 800);
            $('#error').html(output);
  }
  return false;
});
```

or something like that, I am pretty sure the }); in the else is wrong.

Comment: The codes above is working but there is something wrong on it whenever the respond is equal to correct,  an alert box saying correct is not showing up instead the respond was put in the #error element

Comment: the return false position is ok, it doesnt matter because its only will prevent the page from submission to the processor.php.